# HTML element rendered width not equal to set CSS width

Tags: html, css, layout

I have a set of nested HTML, elements that are made up of a parent (AssetContainer) and two main nested parts (MediaViewContainer & AssetDetailsContainer) that are side by side. The right side component (AssetDetailsContainer) has a couple of sub-divs, but they have no styling of their own.
My issue is that the right side component is not rendering at the size it is styled to. The AssetDetailsContainer CSS sets a width of 600px, and this appears in the inspector, but then a different, much smaller value is used to actually render the element. If I set a larger or small value it grows and shrinks but at some non-integer scale of the value that was set. Though "Scaling" is probably a bad term as the rendered value/input value ratio is not a constant.

I'm attaching some images of the inspector panel for the main elements involved in the width, showing their HTML, CSS, and actually rendered properties. I know images aren't ideal, but these seemed to best represent the pertinent data in one place.

**AssetDetailsContainer (right side child element) inspector snapshot**
[image: AssetDetailsContainer (right side child element) inspector snapshot]

Looking at the resulting AssetDetailsContainer shown in the inspector we see the original 600px in the CSS, but then it's rendered as 104.5px instead.

**AssetContainer (parent element) inspector snapshot**
[image: AssetContainer (parent element) inspector snapshot]

**MediaViewContainer (left side child element) inspector snapshot**
[image]

What am I missing here with respect to layout?

Comment: borders can cause this. try applying `box-sizing: border-box` to all elements.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I tested out adding `box-sizing: border-box`, to all elements, then just the ones involved in different combinations and it had no effect.

Comment: I found that if I nest the AssetDetailsContainer in another `<div>` then sizing is correct. It doesn't fix it and produce the layout I want, but it points to some issue with the flex positioning of the AssetContainer and the relative positioning of the AssetDetailsContainer.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the solution was to nest the AssetDetailsContainer in an unstyled `<div>`. I think since the AssetDetailsContainer had a relative positioning property, that was not playing well with the flex positioning of the parent that was being used to create the side-by-side layout. The extra div layer seems to give it the proper segmenting of the different positioning properties and I now get the expected behavior.